# Axibase Time Series Database - report of hits per hour

Tags: time-series, axibase

I am using Axibase Time Series Database Community Edition, version 11499, to store a count every time we hit a particular web service.  How can I get a report of hits per hour for the last 7 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use of of the two built-in [aggregation](https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/widgets/configuring-the-widgets/aggregators/) functions to compute a rate of change over a period of time: DELTA and COUNTER.

Here are some examples:

- [Example 1](https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/e36aa625)
- [Example 2](https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/54e57188)

As you can see, the difference is in how these functions handle resets. The COUNTER function works particularly well for a continuously incrementing metric that might reset (drop to 0 or a negative value) in case of data type overflow or a restart.